# mod_rewrite other rule if more parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I actually use this mod_rewrite for my System to do it SEO friendly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /?c=$1&l=deu
```

I don't know why it works but after hours on try & error this was the solution for me, now I want to extend it.

I want something like

`"if /eng/ is on the end of the url, redirect request to ?c=$1&l=eng"`

In every other case it should use the rule posted above.

Can someone help me please?
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks basic understanding of mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this right after the 301 rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/eng/$ /?c=$1&l=eng [L]
```